# Shp file creates a new column

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, r-sf

Total newb here (thanks in advance!)

In my shp file named "shape", there is a column named "RD_TYPE" and it shows me the types of roads from 1 to 5.

I want to make a simple table that counts how many items there are for each type of road, from the column named "RD_TYPE" :

```
count_rd_type <- shape %>%
  group_by(RD_TYPE) %>%
  count()
```

So when I do this my table is created, but then I see an additional column named "geometry" with coordinates which does not exist in my original dataset "shape". Can someone explain to me how this works?

[screenshot of my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S21N.png)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Assuming you are using `sf` objects, that column is the merge of the roads for each `RD_TYPE`. See the answer of @jindra-lacko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `geometry` column contains (surprise, surprise) the geometry of the roads - meaning a vector representation of your road (coordinates of start, finish, and every segment in between).

Should you find it superfluous you can remove it via `sf::st_drop_geometry()`.

So in your use case consider this code:

```
count_rd_type <- shape %>%
  group_by(RD_TYPE) %>%
  count() %>%
  sf::st_drop_geometry()

class(count_rd_type) # this will be plain old data.frame, not the special sf kind
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm still wondering why the "geometry" column was created when it does not exist in my original dataset. Is this something that is embedded in my "RD_TYPE" column? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you 100% certain geometry was not present in your dataset? Geometry usually is the reason for being of the shapefile, the "why" of a dataset... Anyway, your shapefile likely comes as a bunch of files, try reading in just the dbf one. It will have just the data, no geometry